# How to get many documents from RethinkDB by array of ids?

Tags: ruby, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-ruby

I have array of ids

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, ...] #1000 ids
```

How I can use this function:

```
r.table("users").get_all(1, 2, 3, 4, ..1000 ids.., index: "id")
```

I can use

```
r.table("users").filter{ |doc| r.expr(ids).contains(doc["id"])}
```

But it is too slow on DB with 6 mln docs

methods taken here [SQL to ReQL cheat sheet](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/sql-to-reql/ruby/#select)

Comment: How I can pass array to arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand your `ids` array into a list of arguments (that is expected by the `get_all` method) use the splat operator (`*array`) like this:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
r.table('users').get_all(*ids, index: 'id') # note the `*`
```

Comment: Thank you for help

Comment: I aceepted this answer, but I can't vote, because I have low rating